# Регулярки. Модификатор i. Не учитывать регистр букв

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Помогите, пожалуйста, с регуляркой.

Задача: сделать так, чтобы в регулярке не учитывался регистр букв.

Про модификатор `i` я слышала, но он почему-то не работает.
Вот регулярка:

```
    $regular = '#[регулярка]#iuU';
```

Если честно, то про модификатор `i` и `u` я узнала только что из Гугла. Поэтому если кто-нибудь мне объяснит, как именно его использовать (я слышала про какие-то проблемы с кодировкой), буду очень благодарна.

Сама регулярка работает, это абсолютно точно.

Когда я пытаюсь использовать `iu`, то ничего не происходит. Т.е. регулярка работает, но регистр по-прежнему учитывается.

Comment: Модификатор `i` прекрасно работает: [http://regex101.com/r/eH1eI3][1]

[1]: http://regex101.com/r/eH1eI3

Comment: Вопрос был в том, как сделать так, чтобы работало у МЕНЯ. Так, как вы показали, я тоже делала.
P. S. Ваш овет на ответ сбросился, когда я случайно обновила страницу. Не могли бы вы еще раз написать?

Comment: @Тишина - могли бы вы привести пример кода на ideone.com?
Вот мои наброски: [ideone.com/y2wTrP][1]


  [1]: http://ideone.com/y2wTrP

Comment: Вот код, и в этом сервисе он работает:
http://ideone.com/xjdpT6
А у меня на локалке - нет.
Как Вы думаете, в чем дело?

Comment: Не знаю, поможет ли эта информация, но на всяк случай:
Пользуюсь Вампом:
Apache Version :
2.4.4  
PHP Version :
5.4.16

Comment: @Тишина

> Если честно, то про модификатор i и u я узнала только что из Гугла.

Про модификаторы можео почитать [здесь](http://ru2.php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) и [здесь](http://ru2.php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.internal-options.php)

Comment: @Тишина, в какой кодировке у вас файл?  
Попробуйте установить  

    mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');

Какая версия PHP? Собран ли он с поддержкой PCRE?

Comment: Вопрос решен. Спасибо всем, кто участвовал)

Comment: @Тишина, пожалуйста, проявите уважение к другим пользователям и напишите, что помогло решить вашу проблему и в чем она заключалась. К сожалению, текущее уведомление о том, что вопрос решен, никакой полезной нагрузки не несет.

Comment: Прошу прощения.
В чем заключалась проблема, я написала.
Как я ее решила:
просто подумала, что порядок модификаторов может быть важен. Попробовала поставить их в разном порядке. Рабочий вариант:
'#[регулярка]#Uiu'

Comment: Ума не приложу, почему такой порядок.
Кстати, модификатор 'u' обязателен.

Comment: @Тишина, просто у Вас строка в кодировке юникод, поэтому регистр стал учитываться только с модификатором **u** . Порядок модификаторов не имеет никакого значения.  
Модификатор **U** вовсе никак не влияет на работу с кодировкой и регистрами- он просто делает квантификаторы «нежадными».